# creating list from java 8 stream api

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have an XML schema and generated corresponding POJO classes from JAXB.
The xml sample is provided at the end.

I have a list which holds ship orders. I want to collect all items if the price of the item is more than 100. I was able to do it using java 7 but  thought of doing the same in java 8 using streams. I tried but couldn't achieve the same.
Could some one please help me how to write the code?

```
    List<Shiporder> shiporders = new ArrayList<>();
            shiporders.add(getShipOrder("src/allinone/order1.xml"));
            shiporders.add(getShipOrder("src/allinone/order2.xml"));

<shiporder orderid="Order_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
    <orderperson>Suman pandey</orderperson>
    <shipto>
        <name>Suman pandey</name>
        <address>BTM layout</address>
        <city>Bangalore</city>
        <country>India</country>
    </shipto>
<item>
        <title>Samsung S2</title>
        <note>Special Edition</note>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>100.90</price>
    </item>
<item>
        <title>Oppo</title>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
        <price>20.90</price>
    </item>
</shiporder>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
List<Item> items = shiporders.stream()
                             .map(Shiporder::getItems)
                             .flatMap(List::stream)
                             .filter(it -> it.price > 100)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..:)..I was trying with just filter, map and collect so it was not working, with this example I got to know about one nice use of flatmap..

Comment: @user3305063 Not at all. I'm guessing your classes structure since you never provided anymore. so you maybe need to make some transformations for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
shiporders.stream()
    .filter(new Predicate<Shiporder>(){
        public boolean test(Shiporder shiporder) {
            return <boolean condition on shiporder>;
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.asList);
```

or you can substitute the anonymous inner class with a lambda in the form

```
shiporders.stream()
    .filter(shiporder -> <boolean condition on shiporder>)
    .collect(Collectors.asList);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try using the approach..:)